# Angular 4 - binding not working when declaring variable as a property of an object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a page where I display a list with `locations`, and clicking on each of them I am displaying `assets` for that `location`. I have set up the template like this:

```
<li
    *ngFor="let location of locations"
    (click)="select(location)"
    droppable
    [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
    (onDrop)="onItemDrop($event, location)"
    >
      {{ location.name }}
      <ul *ngIf="currentLocation == location && assetsVisible">
        <ng-container *ngIf="currentLocation.assets?.length > 0;else message">
          <li
            *ngFor="let asset of currentLocation.assets"
            class="asset"
            draggable
            [dragData]="asset"
            >
            <p>{{ asset.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ asset.address }}</p>
            <p>{{ asset.value }}</p>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #message>No assets for {{ location.name }}</ng-template>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

And in the component, I have tried to first set the empty assets array, and an empty `currentLocation` object with a property `assets`:

```
  locations: any[] = [];
  currentLocation: any = {
    assets: any[] = []
  };
```

And then in the method `select` I am fetching the assets like this:

```
  select(location){

    if (this.currentLocation != location || !this.assetsVisible) {
      this.assetsVisible = true;
    }
    else {
      this.assetsVisible = false;
    }

    this.currentAddress = address;

    this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id)
      .subscribe(
        assets => this.currentLocation.assets = assets
      );
  }
```

What I would like to do is to since I am using [the drag and drop plugin for Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-drag-drop#droppable-directive) I would like to make it possible for user to drag assets from one location to another. And then just temporarily push that asset to an array of the property `currentLocation.assets` where the asset was dropped to.
I have made a function for that:

```
onItemDrop(e: any, location) {
    this.select(location);
    this.currentLocation.assets.push(e.dragData);
}
```

That drags and drops the asset from one location to another, but I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I have done `console.log(this.currentLocation.assets)` in both select and onItemDrop method, and both times I get:

> undefined

But, if I do `console.log(this.currentLocation)` in both functions, I get an object with an empty `assets` array as a property of it. And I can access every other property of that object, but I can't access `assets` array.
Also, when I do console.log in `ngOnInit` I get an empty array back in the console:

```
console.log(this.currentLocation.assets);
```

So, I am not sure why do I get this error, why do I get an object with an empty `assets` array as a property of it, but I can't access directly property of that object, when I can access all other properties of the same object?

This is the whole component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from '../services/location.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-addresses',
  templateUrl: 'location.component.html'
})
export class LocationsComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage: string;
  locations: any[] = [];
  currentLocation: any = {
    assets: any[] = []
  };
  assetsVisible: boolean = false;


  constructor(public locationService: LocationService) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocations();
  }


  getLocations() {
    this.locationService.get()
      .subscribe(
        locations => this.locations = locations,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }

  select(location = {}) {

    if (this.currentLocation != location || !this.assetsVisible) {
      this.assetsVisible = true;
    }
    else {
      this.assetsVisible = false;
    }

    this.currentLocation = location;

    this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id)
      .subscribe(
        assets => this.currentLocation.assets = assets,
      );
  }

  onItemDrop(e: any, location:any = {}) {
    this.currentLocation.assets = [];
    this.currentLocation.assets.push(e.dragData);
    this.select(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show us the whole component code?

Comment: I have added the whole component to the question

Comment: seems like you changed some stuff (`this.assets` instead of `currentLocation.assets`)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have changed the code in the meantime, I have just declare the array on it is own, not as a property of the ```currentLocation``` object, and that works, but it is still not working, when I declare it as a property of an object. I have fixed the code, and reverted it to its original state in the question

Comment: this should throw you a compiler error. `currentLocation: any = {
    assets: any[] = [] }` isn't valid syntax. It should be `currentLocation: any = { assets: [] };`

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: you get any errors in your console ? `.subscribe(
        assets => this.currentLocation.assets = assets,
      );` that comma at the end is redundant (and maybe erroneous)

Comment: No, I just get ```undefined``` for the ```console.log(this.currentAddress.assets);```

Comment: can you provide a plunkr? that would be a whole lot easier to fix

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration try this:

```
  locations: any[] = [];
  currentLocation: any = {
     assets: [] 
  };
```

This way you will be declaring `currentLocation` that is an object type `{}` and has a property `assets` that is an array type `[]`.

Comment: Is `this` defined? If so, is `this.currentLocation` defined? Make a couple of console.logs and let me know. If `this` is not defined you are maybe going to have to do `.bind(this)`.

Comment: I get ```undefined```when I do  ```console.log(this.currentAddress.documents);``` but ```this.select(location);``` works